# Umbraco Theme from uskinned website not working

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am using an Umbraco theme from uskinned: https://uskinned.net/

No matter which Umbraco version I use or which browser I use, the theme does not work. I get all these errors: 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asMUr.jpg)

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with .Net Version 4.6.1. It appears as if IIS server setup is blocking requests to the CDN. Please can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your url from http to **https**. It worked for me.
You can also try to use proxy [cors.io](https://cors.io/)